# Incrementing an INI file's section number

Tags: delphi, ini

I have an INI file that stores some integers for settings. The section names are stored like this:

```
[ColorScheme_2]
name=Dark Purple Gradient
BackgroundColor=224
BackgroundBottom=2
BackgroundTop=25
...

[ColorScheme_3]
name=Retro
BackgroundColor=5
BackgroundBottom=21
BackgroundTop=8
...
```

I need to figure out a way to create new sections, that increment the color scheme number +1 from the highest section number. I have a comboBox that lists out the current colorscheme names, so when a user saves to the INI file, the existing scheme is just overwritten. How can I check the ComboBox text to see if it is an existing section and if not, create a new one with an incremented name? (i.e. from the example code above, `ColorScheme_2` and `ColorScheme_3` already exist, so the next section to create would be `ColorScheme_4`).

Comment: Use `ReadSections` to, well, read the sections. Parse them. Increment the number.

Comment: You can use SubSections like [ColorScheme\2] and ReadSubsections to retrieve only the Number Part. But the best solution is to use a Collection and de/serialize the Collection and the Items to the Ini and you don't have to worry about the numbers at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read all sections by using [`ReadSections`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.ReadSections) method, then iterate returned string list and parse each item in it to store the highest found index value:

```
uses
  IniFiles;

function GetMaxSectionIndex(const AFileName: string): Integer;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  Sections: TStringList;
const
  ColorScheme = 'ColorScheme_';
begin
  Result := 0;
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(AFileName);
  try
    Sections := TStringList.Create;
    try
      IniFile.ReadSections(Sections);
      for I := 0 to Sections.Count - 1 do
      begin
        S := Sections[I];
        if Pos(ColorScheme, S) = 1 then
        begin
          Delete(S, 1, Length(ColorScheme));
          if TryStrToInt(S, Index) then
            if Index > Result then
              Result := Index;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Sections.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetMaxSectionIndex('d:\Config.ini')));
end;
```

Comment: I would use `StartsText(ColorScheme, S)` instead of `if Pos(ColorScheme, S) = 1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I would also, if my Delphi version supported this function. (note that OP didn't provide any version info).

Comment: `(Ansi)StartsText()` are available in Delphi 6 onwards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yes, D6/7 has `AnsiStartsText`. But  I try to avoid `Ansi` explicit string functions.

Comment: @kobik: why avoid them?  The `Ansi...()` functions are Ansi in Ansi versions of Delphi, and Unicode (despite their names) in Unicode versions of Delphi.

Comment: @Remy, *I* avoid them because in my non-Unicode Delphi I want to support Unicode as well as in later versions of Unicode Delphi, and Pos supports Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

**How can I check the ComboBox text to see if it is an existing section and if not, create a new one with an incremented name?**

Like this:

```
const
  cPrefix = 'ColorScheme_';
var
  Ini: TIniFile;
  Sections: TStringList;
  SectionName: String;
  I, Number, MaxNumber: Integer;
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create('myfile.ini')
  try
    SectionName := ComboBox1.Text;
    Sections := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Ini.ReadSections(Sections);
      Sections.CaseSensitive := False;
      if Sections.IndexOf(SectionName) = -1 then
      begin
        MaxNumber := 0;
        for I := 0 to Sections.Count-1 do
        begin
          if StartsText(cPrefix, Sections[I]) then
          begin
            if TryStrToInt(Copy(Sections[I], Length(cPrefix)+1, MaxInt), Number) then
            begin
              if Number > MaxNumber then
                MaxNumber := Number;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        SectionName := Format('%s%d', [cPrefix, MaxNumber+1]);
      end;
    finally
      Sections.Free;
    end;
    // use SectionName as needed...
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would use `Format('%s%d', [cPrefix, MaxNumber+1])`

Comment: Yes, that was a copy/paste typo on my part.

Comment: Never heard about `StartsText`, nice to meet. [+1]

Comment: @TLama: there are a lot of useful string functions in the `StrUtils` unit.